# In Django admin list, link the model which doesn't have relationship with object

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models which doesn't have foreign key as relation but has the username column common.

```
class User(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class SessionUser(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I wanted to list all users in Django admin and once clicked on individual object it should list all the session of user. How can we link the object which doesn't have foregien key relationship?

Comment: I recommend you to use a foreign key it has no disadvantage. If you should not use be sure your usernames are unique

Comment: @enesislam   it is from the django_cas_server package. So i can't change their database relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `username` model field **unique** in `User` model.

and Add a **session_users** method in list_display of UserAdmin class

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class UserAdmin(admin.Modeladmin):
    # your user_admin model class
    list_display = ['other_model_fields', 'session_users']
    ...
    ...
    def session_users(self, obj):
        redirect_url = ("%s?username=%s") % (reverse('admin:<app_name>_sessionuser_changelist'), obj.username)
        return format_html('<a class="button" href="{}">Add/View</a>', redirect_url)
```

This will redirect with filtered data of SessionUser model-admin.

Answer (score 0):

i think leaving out the foreign key is not a good idea since there are chances of some usernames to be similar to avoid that, `unique=True` condition should be added.